# Lexmark E240 printing issues

Tags: 14.04, printing, lexmark

I have Lexmark E240 laser printer.
I have been using it with 12.04 (32bit) for 2 years with no significant issues.
Since lexmark does not support this printer on linux, I used alternatives drivers that were suggested by the community, such as HP-lasterjet, E238, generic PS, etc.
They all worked fine, more or less.

After upgrading to 14.04 (64bit fresh install) I tried to configure the printer as before, but now I have problems.

The test page is ok, but when printing, most of the times, the first page in the document will be printed very partially and in 300% zoom. Next page might be ok.
If I turn off the printer and back on, the first page might be ok, but in the next print job, it will be broken again.

I used all the above printer options. Same results.
I did NOT install the lexmark drivers since they are intended for 12.04 and the package manager report that it is in "bad quality" (don't know why).

Does anyone has any experience with this printer in 14.04 64bit ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a late reply, but it may help others that own this printer.

I have just completed a new install of Ubuntu 14.04 and hooked up my Lexmark E210 to my system. The system did not discover it automatically and show me a prompt that a printer was installed and available. However, by going into System Settings and choosing the Printer option, I discovered my printer listed as one of the options. I merely had to select the printer and set it as my default. It works flawlessly. I can't say the same for this printer and Windows 8.